# The cursor in an editable div with a placeholder does not appears at the good place in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a button that clear a simple `editable div` with a placeholder.

If I enter two lines (line break by pressing enter) in the editable div before pressing the button, the placeholder will appear but the cursor will be placed next to the editable div, in Google Chrome.

[image]

I tested with Safari and Firefox, and there's no problem, the cursor is placed in the editable div.

What's wrong with this snippet? ([Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/khrh67mv/4/))

HTML:

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" placeholder="demo"></div>
<button type="button">press me</button>
```

CSS:

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
    content: attr(placeholder);
    display: block;
}

.textarea{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    outline-width: 0;
    cursor: text
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.textarea').empty();
    $('.textarea').focus();
});
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome (version 42) and wasn't able to replicate the issue with your fiddle.  What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on OSX

Comment: You pressed shift + enter and you pressed the button?

Comment: ah, sorry just pressed `shift+enter` but didn't press the button.  I am able to replicate

Comment: You don't see the problem?

Comment: i do see the problem.  It appears related to the `placeholder`. `content: attr(placeholder);`.  Removing that css fixes that issue however then there is no placeholder.  However, I don't have a fix yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this appeared to fix the issue for me, albeit, this fix is a little hacky.  If you set `text` to a `blank space` then it'll fix the issue.

I'm hoping someone else may have a less hackerish fix.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    $('.textarea').text(' ');
    $('.textarea').focus();
    console.log($('.textarea')[0].innerText.length);
});
```

And here is a [fiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/365dw3dj/)

**Edit**

If you want to keep the placeholder then creating a range and setting the selection appears to fix the issue.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    $('.textarea').text('');
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart($('.textarea')[0], 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
});
```

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/bh3s9pkm/)

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard added an edit to the original solution utilizing a `range` element to set the `selection`.

Comment: Damn it works! Hacky, but it's working. I was looking for a css oriented solution, but thanks